# In a linux kernel worker, how do I find all processes that have a file open and kill them?

Tags: linux, process, linux-kernel, kernel, filenames

I'm in a kworker in the linux kernel (assume 3.13).  I'd like to kill all processes that have a specific file open.  For this example, let's assume it's "/dev/video0".  What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: This makes me instantly wonder what ways have you already tried and why any of them aren't the easiest?